# twitter tweets to image using python

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

Can anyone give me some tips how to get tweets from twitter with a certain hashtag and store them like images, for instance using selenium? I know some python code, but I'm very new with it all.

Comment: Do some research (set selenium and navigate to twiter), dont expect that someone will code it for you. If you run into issues then ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going thru a tutorial, and then applying code or concepts from that into a separate personal project.

For example something like this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/twitter-automation-using-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

Please ask for specific questions.

To screenshot certain elements in Selenium, we can do:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<xpath here>")
element.screenshot('elementScreenshot.png')
```

Comment: thanks. this is certainly something i can use